# Log4j RollingFileAppender unknown error

Tags: spring, rabbitmq, log4j, log4jdbc

Error corresponding to log4j.

```
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
log4j:WARN No such property [datePattern] in org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender.
```

There were two files with log4j.properties.
One is in the resources and other is put in a seperate directory.
I combined both of them together.

My log4j.properties file :

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO,R
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection=INFO
log4j.logger.org.springframework=INFO
log4j.logger.medagate=DEBUG
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/medagateRabbitMQ.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=30
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyy-MM-dd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, out, R
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.impl.converter=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.camel.util.ResolverUtil=INFO
log4j.logger.org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection=WARN
log4j.logger.org.springframework=WARN
log4j.logger.org.hibernate=WARN
log4j.logger.net.lshift.camel.component.rabbitmq=DEBUG
log4j.logger.maxim=DEBUG
log4j.appender.out=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.out.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=./logs/medagateRabbitMQ.log
log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%p %t %c - %m%n
log4j.throwableRenderer=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedThrowableRenderer
```

Comment: Why you combined them into one? This way you have duplicated entries i your properties file

Comment: I didn't combined them in the class instead i combined while displaying it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/DailyRollingFileAppender.html

this date pattern is not correct:

```
log4j.appender.R.DatePattern='.'yyyyMMdd
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer fixed the issue.